# How to detect if the current element in a set is the last element?

Tags: c++, foreach, stdset

I have a foreach loop that goes though a `std::set` that looks like

```
for (auto& line : lines){
    //use line
    bool end = /* Check if line is the last element */
}
```

With a `std::vector` I could check `&line == &lines.back();`

Is there a way I can do something similar for a `std::set`?

Comment: I suppose `&line == &*lines.end()`, but it seems a bit questionable.

Comment: @chris, you might want to throw a `- 1` at that `lines.end()` if you don't want to dereference past the end of the set.

Comment: @zneak, Oops, definitely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zneak has some pretty good ideas, but here's one involving iterators in the loop:

```
std::set<std::string> lines;
lines.insert("Hello");
lines.insert("Thar");
lines.insert("How");
lines.insert("Goes");
lines.insert("It");
for (const auto& line : lines) {
    auto it = lines.find(line);
    it++;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (it == lines.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you realize that your solution runs in logarithmic time. Logarithmic is usually pretty good, but for something so easy to do in constant time, it's slightly disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

No, because a set doesn't have a front or a back. However, you could if you used iterators:

```
for (auto iter = lines.begin(); iter != lines.end(); iter++)
{
    bool end = iter + 1 == set.end();
}
```

Alternatively, you could count how many items you've iterated through:

```
size_t count = 0;
for (auto& line : lines)
{
    count++;
    if (count == set.size()) // this is the last element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this way,

```
auto iter = lines.cend();
if (iter!=lines.cbegin())
    --iter;
for (auto &line : lines)
{
    if (*iter==line) // end of the set
    {}
}
```